# Find matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

> Find matrix $A$ if
>
> $$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 2 \\
>         -3 & -4 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> A =  
>        \begin{bmatrix}
>         1 & 0 \\
>         0 & 1 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$

I am just learning this subject and I hope some people can guide me on this because I do not fully understand properties of matrices. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        -3 & -4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Then you have the equation $BA=I$.
To figure out what $A$ is, you want to get rid of the $B$ by multiplying by its inverse on both sides of the equation. This gives: $$B^{-1}BA=B^{-1}I\\IA=B^{-1}\\A=B^{-1}$$

All that is left to do is calculate the inverse of $B$.

Answer (score 4):

There's a formula for this of course, but it more instructive to set
$$A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$$
in the matrix equation. You then get four scalar equations for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, which you can solve.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. 
1) Find the inverse of $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ -3 & -4\end{bmatrix}$.  I would do that as: 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ -3 & -4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Add 3 times the first row to the second row:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Subtract the second row from the first row:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Finally, divide the second row by 2:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -1 \\ \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

So the inverse matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -1 \\ \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

And because the right hand side is the identity matrix, that inverse matrix **is** matrix A.

2) Write A as $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$.  The matrix equation $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -3 & -4 \end{bmatrix}A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ -3 & -4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a+ 2c & b+ 2d \\ -3a- 4c & -3b- 4d \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now solve the 4 equation a+ 2c= 1, b+ 2d= 0, -3a- 4c= 0, and -3b- 4d= 1 for a, b, c, and d.    Multiplying the first equation by 3 and adding that to the third equation, 2c= 3 so c= 3/2.  With c= 3/2, the first equation is a+ 3= 1 so a= -2.  Multiplying the second equation by 3 and adding that to the fourth equation gives 2d= 1 so d= 1/2.  With d= 1/2, b+ 2d= b+ 1= 0 so b= -1.

That gives $A= \begin{bmatrix}-2 & -1 \\ \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ as before.